# Step into (F11) async code in linked project in Visual Studio 2015 not working - how to fix

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 RC, while I can step into async functions within a console app that is part of the solution (the startup solution), or else, from a Unit Test project also within the solution, when I step into functions located in a separate project that exists within the solution, it does *not* step into it (using F11 etc) but just completes (steps over) the function call.

So I have to go to that function code and set a break point there for it to step into it, but even then, further function calls within that function again don't step into, but require, again, further breakpoints set on them first. This could drive someone crazy quickly, I hope there is some fix for this?!

---

Update: I just opened the same solution in Visual Studio 2013, and it works perfectly. So this really appears to be an issue in VStudio 2015 (RC) alone.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [a related bug in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30331721/264031) fixed this problem (*what* a relief). I had both of these bugs happening.

Reset all Visual Studio user data by running this command (for me it worked to run this from the regular Windows Run command):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /ResetUserData
```

You'll probably want to export some settings first (Tools > Import and Export Settings).

--- UPDATE ---

You can also just use the IDE to do this in Visual Studio:

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings
```