# Visual Studio thinks `Microsoft Web Developer Tools` is installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

**Symptoms**

- Visual Studio syntax highlighter and Intellisense for `Javascript` and `Razor` views are not working.
- There is no `Web` templates installed when creating a new project.
- When I try to uninstall the web developer feature:

  `Add or remove Programs > Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 > Modify`

  `Microsoft Web Developer Tools` is always checked. Even when I uncheck it and uninstall it, then restart the computer; the next time I still see it's checked:

  [image]

**What I did to solve this:**

- Running `devenv.exe \resetuserdata` Command to reset the user data.
- Running `devenv.exe \installtemplates` to install the templates.
- Repairing the Visual Studio.
- Trying to uninstall and re-install the `Web Developer Tools` feature through the Visual Studio installer.

None have worked so far.

**What I guess**

I think Visual Studio thinks this feature is installed (through some registry keys probably) but the files are actually not installed.

Because whenever I try to `Modify` the installation of Visual Studio, the `Microsof Web Developer Tools` check box is not checked for the first second, then it is checked again after 1 second.

**Question**

Any suggestion on fixing this without uninstalling Visual Studio itself?

Comment: I have this exact same problem with VS2015 Update 2... Cannot get it to work. Have tried everything I can find on SO including uninstalling and reinstalling TWICE. Still same problem you are experiencing. Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Except uninstall-reinstalling VS not really

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem and this is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall ASP.NET Web Tools from Control Panel
   [image: program listing in control panel]
2. Download and install "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" extension from:  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935

Comment: I have been stuck on this issue for THREE DAYS now. This is the ONLY thing that has worked for me. I owe you a drink! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

Try this (in order):

1. Find `Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC1 ...` in control panel / programs &
   select `modify`
2. Select `repair`
3. Run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` as **administrator**
4. Run VS as **administrator**

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015. I tried several things, but simply updating Microsoft ASP.NET seemed to do the trick.

Install [ASP.NET 5 RC1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935/file/77371/6/AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe?SRC=VSIDE&UPDATE=TRUE), restart, and the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know I had this problem until I opened an MVC project with Razor views and didn't have syntax highlighter and Intellisense. I was lucky to read your question because the symptoms are the same and so is the conclusion. And unfortunately none of the answers solves the problem. But it did help me to find the answer, or what worked for me.

What did the trick was installing **.NET Core 1.0.0** ([DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-Runtime-x64 and DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download)). I am pretty sure that this is enough to solve the issue. But since I tried all kinds of things, it is possible that another action is required. In that case, continue reading below the images.

When I start a new project this opens the following dialog:

[image: Dialog New Project]

Selecting *ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)* opens the dialog with the projects I was looking for.

[image: Dialog Web Application]

The syntax highlighter and Intellisense are also working for Razor views.

I do not know what caused the problem in the first place. Is the installation incomplete, is there a conflict with other software or did I do something that caused this?

Visual Studio 2012 is installed on my machine as well. I installed and uninstalled VS2015 (pro and community version) and then installed vs2015 Community on multiple volumes. On uninstalling I did use /Force and removed several folders manually.

Microsoft ASP.NET 5 RC Update 1 is also installed, but repairing this did not solve the issue. Also installing **Asp.Net Web Framework tools 2015** didn't change anything. I copied templates to all template folders I could find (perhaps an issue with installing on multiple volumes?), ran devenv.exe with different parameters and deleted the '14' folder in my profile. None of this worked. Finally I installed .NET Core 1.0.0.