# Visual Studio @helper formatting (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

Visual Studio formatting for Razor **@helper**s is broken.

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3**

[image: Broken formatting for @helpers in VS]

How to fix it?

Comment: Usually when something in Razor formatting is broken, you need to wait for a new release of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Stijn **Visual Studio 15 Preview 4** has same problem.

Comment: It took a few years for them to fix the formatting problem that occurred when using tabs instead of spaces. Your best option is to raise an issue on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and hope they fix it at some point. Be sure to be as detailed as possible (example code, expected result, actual result).

Comment: Or just don't use `@helper`, since it's a bad idea anyways. Move the code into an `HtmlHelper` extension. That way, it's easily testable and you'll see any potential issues at compile-time, rather than run-time.

Comment: Is it just the @helper or is the syntax highlighter and Intellisense also not working? Do you have .NET Core 1.0.0 installed?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg anything else works fine, only formatting broken. I have .NET Core installed, but this is an ASP.NET MVC 5 project (not .NET Core)

Comment: The reason I asked, there may be a connection. I had a somewhat different problem, I lost syntax highlighter and intellisense (for mvc project) and found out that I had to reinstall .NET Core. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245041/visual-studio-thinks-microsoft-web-developer-tools-is-installed/37756993#37756993