# The following references must be present before installation can continue "Web Developer Tools"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently reinstalled Visual Studio 2015, and I made sure I picked Web Developer Tools when I installed it. However, when I go to install Web Essentials through the Extensions and Updates popup, I get this message:

[image]

When I go to modify my installation of Visual Studio 2015, I can see that Web Developer Tools has been installed (or at least marked for installation):

[image]

I am now unable to install Web Essentials, because I get this message. What can I do?

Comment: Try one of these solutions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245041/visual-studio-thinks-microsoft-web-developer-tools-is-installed

Comment: @DipenShah Trust me, dude, I tried everything I could find.