# How to I get MVC 5 template for VS 2015 Community

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How do I get MVC 5 template in new install of VS2015 COmmuniyt?

WHen I start new project, the is no Web template.

Under "online" there only seem to be 3rd party templates - not MSDN ones.

I saw on suggestion to use Tools/Extension - but I don't have this option!

Can someone give me a pointer please

Comment: Go into your control panel and uninstall Visual studio, when you click that you get three options, Uninstall, Modify, and repair (I think) - Click modify and you can install the web developer tools

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `web developer tools`.
To fix this issue you need to check this option like in the picture below during the installation.
[image]

Steps:

1. In control panel
2. Select Add or Remove programms
3. From the list select VisualStudio
4. Modify
5. Repair and then on the Features list under the Windows and WebDevelopment node select `Microsoft Web Developers Tools`.

Comment: @ManInMoon maybe you need to have a look at this post then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245041/visual-studio-thinks-microsoft-web-developer-tools-is-installed