# VS 2015 Intellisense issue?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Can someone tell me why the intellisense behaviour in VS 2015 is so different?
The "showdialog" method in this example is not detected and shown. Yet if I type it out without using intellisense, it actually works. In VS 2012 this works perfectly.

[image]

Here is a link to my [VS 2015 project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30964827/Temp/Showdialog.zip).

Comment: Please, verify if it is related with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30311355/890890. If is, se my answer there

Comment: Hi,No its not related. Its some of the items in the inteisense list that does not appear for some reason. In this case the "Showdialog" method. Any idea why not or what I could try to sort it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net intellisense is returning form classes, rather than My.Forms.etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452569/vb-net-intellisense-is-returning-form-classes-rather-than-my-forms-etc)