# New MVC Web Application has no Razor recognition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I just created a new ASP.Net Web Application in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Solution > Add New Project > Visual c# > Web > .NET Framework 4.5.2 > ASP.Net Web Application

In the 'Select a Template' dialog, I selected MVC.

In the packages.config file is this line:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

However, none of the usual Razor highlighting is working, and I'm not getting any intellisense.

[image]

Comment: Did you check for Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense).

Just delete the contents of this directory with Visual Studio closed:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

weird.