# Is it normal that Razor doesn't highlighting syntax of C# when also is JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, syntax-highlighting

Is it normal that Razor doesn't highlighting syntax of C# when also is JavaScript?

[Here is screen of my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkkKK.png)

I can't even debug the code of C#. In the other view where is only C#, HTML and CSS everything is all right.

Thanks for any response!

Comment: It looks like your Razor _is not_ being highlighted and the javascript **is**

Comment: Here is solution to this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense

Comment: If resetuserdata not work, tried to put a cursor on it. in some case it's load when you put pointer on the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 not syntax highlighting razor nor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense)

Comment: I didn't add, but it is Visual Studio 2017 and I can't find devenv.exe /ResetUserData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResetUserData didn't help.

I found the different solution and it works for me:

Opening the same project as a "Web Site" (File > Open > Web Site) fixes the issue.